# Particles converted but materials are linked

Tags: materials, particles

I converted a particle system with sphere objects.

I want to individually change the colors of objects.

It is linked, when changing the color of an instanced object it changes all others to that color.

Help?

Comment: You need to assign different materials to those you want to change.

Comment: The material 'assign' option is not coming in the object mode. It comes in edit mode

Comment: You can select them and make them single user: object mode, menu "object/relations".

Comment: Or click on the number right next to the material name, to make a copy of the materia, that you can then modify to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround would be to utilize the **Random** output of a **Object Info** node in the shader graph, plugging it into a **Hue/Saturation** node input. In this way you could randomly vary the hue or the saturation or both. I personally utilize a **Bright/Contrast** node in between to get the hues I need.
[image]

But I think the real issues is to be found in where exactly this material information is stored. You can conveniently decide weather to store it in mesh data or in object data opting in this drop-down menu in the material property panel.

[image]

If materials are assigned in mesh data ("Data") every instance (meaning linked copy) of that object will have the those materials and if you change them they will change over all objects. Otherwise if materials are stored in the object data-block different linked object will be able to have different materials.

If you prefer proceeding this way you'll have to change this property before converting the particle system, in the original sphere.